# What are valid characters for Java's keytool's alias?

Tags: keytool

What characters are valid in an 'alias' for Java 7's `keytool` command?

I found this page - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html - but it doesn't seem to explain in detail what's a valid alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source for `keytool` doesn't validate it at all, it just calls methods of [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), so it comes down to what `KeyStore` will accept, which appears to be any string, subject to the case-sensitivity *caveat* in its Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks. I found that caveat here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/security/KeyStore.html. And I guess that means I can pass anything to it I can pass via the shell, so this is more shell-dependant than keytool dependant.